# Using bootstrap input-group-addon adds an extra line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to used bootstrap's input-group-addon, but using it puts the addon as an extra line beneath the input field.

for example this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="tankDiameter">Tank Diameter:</label>
   <input type="number" min="0" id="tankDiameter" name="tankDiameter" class="form-control"  ng-model="tankFormCtrl.tank.diameter" placeholder="Tank diameter in cm" ng-keyup="tankFormCtrl.calculateValues()" required>
   <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
</div>
```

will result in:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the two inputs inside the class `input-group` so that they are inline. If you want to control the sizing of the input box, add the grid classes `col-xs-*` to the input-group as well.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tankDiameter">Tank Diameter:</label>
  <div class="input-group col-xs-4">
    <input type="number" min="0" id="tankDiameter" name="tankDiameter" class="form-control" ng-model="tankFormCtrl.tank.diameter" placeholder="Tank diameter in cm" ng-keyup="tankFormCtrl.calculateValues()" required>
    <span class="input-group-addon">cm</span>
  </div>
</div>
```